# Detect squeezebox close

Tags: javascript, mootools, squeezebox

Hi is there a way to detect [SqueezeBox](http://digitarald.de/project/squeezebox/) closed by user?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Squeezebox has an event for that.

`this.fireEvent('onClose', [this.content]);`

so when you make your squeezebox, just add:

```
SqueezeBox.initialize({
    onClose: function() {
        alert('dont close me');
    }, 
    other: 'options'
});
```

btw - this is really old. you should get a more upto date lightbox.

Comment: Is there a way to prevent the squeezebox from closing?

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to do this: Squeezebox's close button has an id of *sbox-btn-close* so you can attach a click event to that using jQuery.

```
$('#sbox-btn-close').click(function(){
      alert('Squeezebox closed');
});
```

Comment: 1. this is not jquery. 2. you can close it by esc or by clicking on the overlay.